Bernoulli 1/n a.s convergence
I need helo to get a better understanding of almost sure convergence!
If a sequence $(X_n),n\in\mathbb N$ of independent r.v. is $Bernoulli(\frac{1}{n})$ distributed. Then it converges in Distribution and Probability to $X=0$ but does not almost surely converge to $X=0$.
Well almost sure convergence is a weaker form of pointwise convergence known from real analysis, where we can neglect nullsets with respect to the probability measure $ \mathbb P$. In other words the r.v. does not need to converge on $\Omega$ its enough, that it converges on a subset $\Omega_0\subset\Omega$ with $\mathbb P((\Omega_0)^c)=0$. Did i got that right?
Back to the exercise the convergence in distribution and probability is not a problem for me to show, i will not write it down here.
Well, let $X_1,X_2,...:\{0,1\}\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ are those Beroulli(1/n) distributed random variables. $X_n(0)=0, X_n(1)=1\forall n\in \mathbb N$. Well $X_n(1)=1$ constantly it does not tends to $0$ for $n\rightarrow\infty$ its probability just shrinks to $0$ $X(1)=0\neq 1$ where $X=0$ is the r.v. which is identical $0$ on {0,1} how do i write this down as an acutal proof? Just like above and deduce that convergence almost surely doesnt follows from that?

Are $X_n$'s independent?

@geetha290krm yes they are, forgot that, i will edit!

In your own interest I would like to mention that omitting independence assumptions is  a very very serious mistake and your teachers will surely penalize you for that.

@geetha290krm of course, you are right!, Thanks for your simple solution in this case!

$\sum P(X_n=1)=\sum \frac 1 n =\infty$. By independence and Borel-Cantelli Lemma $X_n=1$ for infinitely many $n$, with probabilty $1$. Hence, $X_n \to 0$ with probability $0$.
